# Detecting whether or not a page has been updated in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm wiring a Chrome Extension that needs to run its main function every time the contents of a tab are updated (for example, the page automatically loads new posts). I've been using the following to detect this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        blah blah blah...
    }
}
```

But this only detects if a tab's URL has been changed or if the user manually refreshes the page. Ideally, I'd also like the extension to ignore occurrences where the user clicks a link/anchor within the page, as while that changes the URL, the page does not receive any new content.

Comment: There's no chrome API for this. You can use common techniques: MutationObserver or subscribing to page events like `pjax:end` on github.com showcased in at least several answers on StackOverflow. If you need a specific answer then provide more details (site url, for example).

Comment: I'll look into MutationObserver.  Thanks for the info!